# Spring Batch: ItemReader have issues in @Value(“#{stepExecutionContext[filename]}”)

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using a Partitioner. The job works fine, but when I'm trying to use stepExecutionContext to get data from Partitioner class I get it null in ItemReader:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<ClassName> Reader(
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileResource']}") String file) {
    FlatFileItemReader<ClassName> fileReader=new FlatFileItemReader<ClassName>();
    fileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(file));
    return fileReader;
}
```

Partitionner Class looks like:

```
public class PartitionerClass implements Partitioner {

   private String rep;

   @Override
   public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    File dir = new File(rep);
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
         File[] files = dir.listFiles();
           for (File file : files) {
               if(file.isFile()) {
                 ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
                 context.putString("fileResource", file.getName());
                 partitionMap.put(file.getName(), context);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return partitionMap;
            }
     public String getRep() {
      return rep;
       }

     public void setRep(String rep) {
     this.rep = rep;
        }
}
```

Calling Partitioner Class:

```
@Bean
    public FilesPartitioner partitioner() {
        PartitionerClass partitioner = new PartitionerClass();
        partitioner.setRep("MyDirectory");
        return partitioner;
    }
```

Comment: Which partitioner do you use? Does it add a key named `fileResource` to the step execution context? Please share its configuration/code to be able to help you.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I edited the code, Thank you for looking at my question

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code/config. Are you sure that `partitionMap` is not empty when you unit test your partitioner (aka `dir.isDirectory()` returns true and the directory is not empty)?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes I already test it using   System.out.println(context.get("fileResource")); it display all file names. Is there something wrong with @StepScope?

Comment: I configured the Reader in the same class with Step and it works, I don't know if this is the way supposed to do it or not.

Comment: Glad you fixed your issue.